# using lapply to apply a function on a list with different number of element

Tags: r

I am starting to code on R recently, I have a problem, I looked a lot but I could not figure it out.
I have a list like below and I am trying to apply this function to this list. What I am expecting to find is a single value for each Falses and trues.
But when I used the lapply function I am getting this warning:
 In if (x) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
Where I am making mistakes? Thank you in advance.

```
function(x) {if(x)
{runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR)} else {runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR)}}

[[1]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

[[6]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

[[7]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is using the `if` function on vectors (the list elements). You should use `ifelse`:

```
lapply(L, function(x){ifelse(x, runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR), runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR))})
```

For example:

```
L = list(c(F,T),c(F,F,F,T))
VAR = 1
IQ = 3

lapply(L, function(x){ifelse(x,runif(1, IQ - VAR, IQ + VAR), runif(1,0.20 - VAR , 0.20 + VAR))})

[[1]]
[1] -0.1924877  2.0677188

[[2]]
[1] 1.158114 1.158114 1.158114 2.408010
```

Comment: Yep. It helps so much. Thank you!